# Python - New Column in Dataframe using values of 2 other columns

Tags: python, dataframe, conditional-statements, logic

I have a dataframe titanic_df. Want to create a new column that has a value of 1 if SibSp is 0 AND Parch is 0. Can someone please tell me if the method below is efficient?

```
titanic_df['Alone'] = [1 if x == 0 & y == 0 else 0 for x,y in list(zip(titanic_df.SibSp,titanic_df.Parch))]
```

I know that in SAS it would literally be

```
data dset;
     set dset;
     if sibsp = 0 and Parch = 0 then alone = 1;
     else alone = 0;
run;
```

It just seems to me like creating a new column based on values from 2 other columns should be a bit easier?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a new  column and initialize it with 0, for example

```
titanic_df['Alone'] = 0
```

Then you set 1 to the cells which SibSp and Parch are equal to 0

```
titanic_df.loc[(titanic_df['SibSp'] == 0) & (titanic_df['Parch'] == 0), 'Alone'] = 1
```

From what I know, your solution isn't very efficient, since it creates a zip object with your DataFrame (columns SibSp and Parch), then transforms it to a list and finally loops through it.